# Autopopulate values based on code in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to define certain things in excel like when I type some code(ex 112) in a new sheet, it will automatically import data from a separate sheet and display the contents of it in other columns.

FOR EX

```
112    agarwal male
119    reena   female
```

That is, when i type 112 in a column, it will automatically display agarwal and male in the same row but in different columns(The whole data from where it will import is present in  an another sheet).

Comment: Sounds like you need a database, not a spreadsheet.

Comment: I want to create a database and then want to use it in excel

Comment: yes , from a seperate dedicated excel sheet

Comment: Are you familiar with VLOOKUP ?

Answer (score 1):

Use of the `IF` statement in a formula will do what you seek. The `IF` function checks for a logical value (true or false) then takes action on that result.

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

So, by having it check the "code" it will know what values to place in the cells of other columns. If you are typing the "code" in A1, then put this formula in B1

```
=IF(A1=112,"agarwal",IF(A1=119,"reena",""))
```

Place this formula in C1

```
=IF(A1=112,"male",IF(A1=119,"female",""))
```

As you can see, the first one checks for the code `112`, if it's `TRUE` it places the word "agarwal" in the cell. If it is `False` it goes to the next instructions which happen to be nested `IF` statement. At the end of the statement it will leave the cell blank if neither returns `TRUE`.

You can copy the formulas down the rows by double clicking the lower right corner.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.Actually i am having a separate sheet which contains all the data.What I want is if i write the first value(ex 112) in another separate sheet, i want it to automatically import all that data  from that sheet.

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question with those details. My answers was based on the question you asked. It is important to include as much detail as possible when asking your questions. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using just excel and formula's, no VBA etc (EDIT - this will only work in Excel 2007 or later)...

In a document called `Book1.xls` you have the following table containing your base information - NO FORMULAS:

[image]

Then in a document called `Book2.xls` you have the table you want to auto update.

In `Cell A1` you put the number you are searching for (in this case `112`). In `Cell B1` place the following code:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$C$2;2;0);"what")
```

This will look up the contents of `Cell A1` in the area between `A1` and `C2` in `Sheet1` of document `Book1.xlsx` (note the documents in this case need to be in the same folder) and if it finds them it will display the contents of the cell with `col index = 2` (the col index starts at number 1 at the first column in your array)

In this case your array is the contents from `A1` to `C2` but the information you are looking for will always be in `Column A` so `col index = 1` is `Column A`, `col index = 2` is `Column B` and `col index = 3` is `Column C`.

In `Cell C1` replace the last `2` in the above formual with a `3`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$C$2;3;0);"")
```

Now, enter a number in `Cell A1` in your sheet and if it matches a number somewhere in the array `A1` to `C2` in your reference document then the contents of cells `B1` and `C1` will automatically be updated with the name and sex of the matched item.

Comment: A solution without VBA is of course always better, but let me kindly add two notes: =IFERROR isn't available in Excel 2003 and the OP forgot to mention which version he is using. Also you need to copy the formula around to every column you want to populate.

Comment: TY for your comment, I was not aware IFERROR was not available pre-2007 but you are correct, I have edited my answer to indicate this.

Comment: @nixda `IFERROR` may be replaced by `IF(ISERROR(...))` combination for earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin...it is working and my problem is solved...:)

Comment: @neeraj You should mark the answer which solved your problem as accepted with a green check mark